# how can I get the clients connected to my mongodb with java plugin?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo db instance and I want to get all the clients connected to it. In the mongo shell I write

```
db.currentOp(true)
```

And I get all the clients and their properties.
How can I pull that data in java?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
mongoclient.getDB("local").command("currentOp")
```

It says that there is not such a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `currentOp` is a command on the shell, but it is not a *first-class* mongodb command supported in all drivers.  You will need to query the `$cmd.sys.inprog` collection with `findOne()`. With `java` driver you can do the following (which is exactly what `currentOp` calls under the hood):

```
DB db = mongoclient.getDB("local");
DBObject currentOp = db.getCollection("$cmd.sys.inprog").findOne();
```

If you look what is going on under the hood when calling `currentOp` you get the idea:

```
> db.currentOp
function ( arg ){
    var q = {}
    if ( arg ) {
        if ( typeof( arg ) == "object" )
            Object.extend( q , arg );
        else if ( arg )
            q["$all"] = true;
    }
    return this.$cmd.sys.inprog.findOne( q );
}
>
```

Comment: Thanks! It runs fluently!

Comment: It appears to me that it does not matter what database you are currently on wither. I can be on the "foo" db and I get Ops that are in the "bar" namespace ("ns" attribute).